# Where can I find the doc for a specific API version?

Tags: node.js

The current nodejs version is not 0.10.0 so if I go on http://nodejs.org/api/ website, I can only see the latest doc. I have to work with node 0.8.21. Where can I find the doc for this version?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look in http://nodejs.org/docs/ and you can see all the older versions listed out, including v0.8.21.

Select your version and it will bring you to the site of that version, you can then select "API Docs" and view the docs for that version.

You can also use this link: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.21/api/ and replace with your version number.

Comment: Browsing through the old versions doesn't work for me anymore, the API Docs link from the old page takes me to the latest version of the docs.  I had to manually type in the version into the link.