# Node.js 0.10 online documentation

Tags: node.js, documentation

After Node.js v0.12 release the [official documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/) now does not allow us to browse node v0.10 docs anymore.

**Is there online node.js documentation for v0.10 (not the latest one)?**

Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the doc for a specific API version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365162/where-can-i-find-the-doc-for-a-specific-api-version) ?

Here you go: http://nodejs.org/docs/

Or more specifically, for 0.10.0: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.0/api/

Comment: Indeed this question is a duplicate. Although I couldn't find the answer using search. Which is bad.

Comment: You're right, using intuitive keywords I don't find it from the Stack Overflow search either.  I found it on Google: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=old+node+documentation