# Where is the node.js v0.10.x doc?

Tags: node.js

All the node.js documentation seems to be linking to v0.12 documentation.

I have existing code. I can run the recent node v0.10.36 but I don't think I'm ready to jump to 0.12. In [particular](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Api-changes-between-v0.10-and-v0.12#buffers) my Buffers code will likely break.

Is this some sort of conspiracy? Where are the docs for 0.10?

Comment: I found my answer on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446064/node-js-0-10-online-documentation), the docs are [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.0/api/).

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.0/api/

Comment: Thanks @BenFortune, I wonder why google is making it hard to find it.